# Java Getting values of 0 in Array

Tags: java

So i have to make a beer pong game for my class but when i try to print out the values i inserted in the array cups1[#], cups2[#] they all come out as if i inserted a number 0 which i do not get because i do not have anything inserting a 0 into the array and every time i print i see lots of 0 s in the console. Each ball i insert in the cup has to have a number and that's why i want to print which ball went to which cup my cups are my cups array, i will add an for loop to print the numbers in array but as in right know i want to know why the array is only getting 0 s inserted.

this are my codes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cups1[] = new int[9];

    int cups2[] = new int[9];

    int cup1 = 1;

    int cup2 = 1;

    int balls = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 2);

        if (random == 0) {
            cups1[cup1] = balls;
            cup1++;
            balls++;
            System.out.println(cups1[cup1]);
        }

        if (random == 1) {
            cups2[cup2] = balls;
            cup2++;
            balls++;
            System.out.println(cups2[cup2]);
        }

        if (cups1[0] >= 1 && cups2[0] >= 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I'm getting
[image: Output]

Comment: why are you initialising `cup1` and `cups` to 1?

Comment: I guess your problem is that you're printing `cups1[cup1]` and `cups2[cup2]`AFTER having incremented `cup1` or `cup2`.

Answer (score 0):

Let dissect your code to show you why this happens:

```
cups1[cup1]=balls; // #1
cup1++; // #2
balls++;
System.out.println(cups1[cup1]); // #3
```

Let's assume that this is the first round, so `cup1` is 1 and `balls` is 1.

- Line #1: you assign the current value of balls (1) to `cups1[1]`, `cups1` now contains "0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0"
- Line #2: you increment `cup1`, so `cup1` is now 2
- Line #3: you print out `cups1[2]`, which still has it's default value 0

By reordering the lines you will see the assigned numbers:

```
cups1[cup1]=balls;
System.out.println(cups1[cup1]);
cup1++;
balls++;
```

The complete code probably still doesn't do what you want, but this is hard to tell...